# How to use this raycast to activate an interaction script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, interaction

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private DialogueUI dialogueUI;

    private DialogueActivator dialogueA;

    public Vector3 raypositionup = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
    public Vector3 raypositiondown = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);

    private float MoveSpeed = 7f;

    public Animator animator;

    public DialogueUI DialogueUI => dialogueUI;

    public Interactable Interactable { get; set; }

    bool move = false;
    bool movefoward = false;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    private void Start()
    {
        dialogueA = GetComponent<DialogueActivator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (DialogueUI.IsOpen) return;

        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            move = true;
            movefoward = false;
            animator.SetBool("Lookingfoward", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            movefoward = true;
            move = false;
            animator.SetBool("Lookingfoward", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            MoveSpeed = 10f;
        }
        else
        {
            MoveSpeed = 7f;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            if (Interactable != null)
            {
                Interactable.Interact(this);
            }
        }

        if (move == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {

                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + raypositionup, transform.up * .01f, Color.red);

                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + raypositionup, transform.up, .01f);

                if (hit.collider == null)
                {
                    return;
                    dialogueA.enabled = false;
                }
                else if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Object")) //No catched if null
{
                    Debug.Log("Poop");
                    hit.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
        }
        if (movefoward == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {

                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + -raypositionup, -transform.up * .01f, Color.red);

                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + -raypositionup, -transform.up, .01f);

                //Stops compile error if the raycast hits nothing
                if (hit.collider == null)
                {
                    dialogueA.enabled = false;
                    return;
                }

                //If the raycats does hit something, then perform an action
                else if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Object")) //No catched if null
                {
                   
                    Debug.Log("Poop");
                    hit.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

I'm using the raycast in this script to check if the character is looking at the object to interact with it. I have separate scripts for interaction alone, and I wanted to know how I would make it so when the raycast hit something, and the player is in the correct radius (set up in another script), it activates the interactable script. I'm unsure how to activate and disable my interactable ( script that makes the dialog box pop up) script from this script, only when the raycast is active. I would also like to know how to use the same getKeyDown for both shooting the raycast, and opening the dialogue box(Enter key). Does anyone know how to do this, and does anyone have and fixes to my code. I'm new to coding, and any criticism is welcome and encourage :)

Comment: Well depends a little what you mean by interactable by the sounds of it you want to trigger a dialog. Well raycast forward. If interactable object found. Call some form of start doing things method.

Comment: Yes, I have a script that brings the dialogue box when the player is in a certain range of the object and presses enter, I was wondering how I could have the raycast activated with enter as well, and only while the raycast is active and the player is in range the dialogue is brought up.

Comment: Set a property on the player basically saying im looking at x. Then in the dialog bit check that property